# How to convert object property in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a mysql database, where I've start column(Datetime) and duration(Time). In laravel/vue app I fetch this information for events array in V-Calendar. How can I convert/get **end** property for event.

```js
getAllEvent() {
  return this.$store.getters.getEvents.map(x => ({
      ...x,

      start: x.start,
      end: x.start.plus({ minutes: x.duration.minutes() }),
      id: x.id,
  }));
}
```

Because now (I use luxon library) I do get

> Type.Error: x.start.plus is not a function.

Comment: You need to convert `start` to a `DateTime` object in Luxon first before you can use the properties from a DateTime object against it: `DateTime.fromSQL(x.start).plus({minutes: x.duration.minutes()).toSQL())`

Comment: Unfortunately i get the same error.